# Authorizing external URL for Google Cloud Security Scanner

Tags: security, url, web-applications

I've searched around but cannot find how to authorize Google Cloud Security Scanner to scan an external starting URL (a test website not hosted on the Google cloud platform). Any hints?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

At this time, Cloud Security Scanner can only scan apps hosted on AppEngine. Sorry.